# what DataAnnotation to make an SQL Identity column?

Tags: webforms, entity-framework-5

I have the following in my class and need to know how to modify the DataAnnotation to make it an identity column

```
public class Item
{
    public Int16 ItemID { get; set; }
}
```

The goal is to have the EF5.0 equivalant of the SQL

```
ItemID smallint IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DatabaseGenerated attribute with DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity. You can find more details about configuring EF with attributes here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583 and about DatabaseGnerationOption enum here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption.aspx. You can also configure your model with Fluent API - here are some examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617

Comment: Thanks I had found the first two links but there was such little information on them about what the .Identity does I was not sure if it would set the seed and intervalt to 0,1 like I want.